# Recyclerview item postion NOT_FOUND after scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So i have a parent `recyclerview` with vertical orientation and a child `recyclerview` nested with parent with horizontal orientation.

`Onclick` function goes with child recylerview

I have created an interface which gives the adapter position of child item back to parent adapter class.

**TEST CASE**

1. Display the `recyclerview` and click on any child item.

***result - working fine***

2. Scroll down the `recyclerview` and click on any child item.

***result - working fine***

3. Manually Scroll back to 1st position and now click on any child item.

***result - parent `recylerview` position is -1 (FAILED TEST CASE)***

What can be the possibilities of this?
*If you need any code i can provide it by editing*

**Parent ViewHolder class**

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        RecyclerView reClassList;


        ViewHolder(View itemView, final Context context) {
            super(itemView);


            reClassList = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycle_garage_list_class);

            garageListEvents = new GarageListEvents() {
                @Override
                public void getChildPositon(int childPosition) {

                    // TODO Remove
                    Log.e("GARAGE ADAPTER","Garage List Position :"+String.valueOf(getLayoutPosition()));
                }
            };
        }
```

**Child ViewHolder Class**

```
 public class ClassViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ClassViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                garageListEvents.getChildPositon(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**INTERFACE**

```
public interface GarageListEvents {

public void getChildPositon(int childPosition);
}
```

**FYI** - GarageAdapter is the parent adapter

Comment: Provide adapters and viewholders please. :)

Comment: Ok let me edit it

Comment: @MilanKundacina Done editing

Comment: I guess it has to do something with recycling viewholders.
Try to set this to both viewholders `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`. It won't be very good for performace, but we will see if that is issue.

Comment: Yes man, It this solution have solved my issue. Thanks a lot. Please put it as an answer I shall accept it.

Comment: And i have only done this change in parent viewholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it has to do something with recycling viewholders. Try to set this to parent viewholder `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`. It will have little impact on performace, but it should solve problem.